# Why am I receiving an error when I include && and a second string evaluation

Tags: bash

Using Bash Version 4.4

Working Bash Code:

```
# Hello World Program in Bash Shell

MY_NAME="John"
NAME_1="Kate"
if [ ${MY_NAME} == "John" ]; then
    echo "John and Kate are home from vacation"
fi
```

Failing Bash Code:

Error:

```
# Hello World Program in Bash Shell

    MY_NAME="John"
    NAME_1="Kate"
    if [ ${NAME_1} == "Kate" && ${MY_NAME} == "John" ]; then
        echo "John and Kate are home from vacation"
    fi
```

main.sh: line 5: [: missing `]'

Comment: See [Bash Pitfalls #6](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#A.5B_.22.24foo.22_.3D_bar_.26.26_.22.24bar.22_.3D_foo_.5D). And please don't post images of code. Paste your code into the editor, select the code you want to format and use the `{}` "code sample" button.

Comment: Please don't post code as a picture, post it as text instead

Comment: @Freddy Thanks for the resource, I'm new to bash.

Comment: You're welcome @AdrianJ.! Also have a look at [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/), this is a site where you can check your scripts online.

Answer (score 1):

`[` doesn't support `&&` inside, use `-a` instead.

`[[` supports `&&`

So you can replace `&&` with `-a`, or replace `[` and `]` with `[[` and `]]`

For example:

```
[ 1 -eq 1 -a 2 -eq 2 ]

[[ 1 -eq 1 && 2 -eq 2 ]]
```